# How can I fix this corrupted.ad1 file

Tags: binary

I failed a CTF challange and I have been searching all over the internet looking for solutions but didn't get one. Can someone help me so that I can fix the image and get the CTF flag. Here is link to the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D3cZ8MN9MTD2DOuN1d--1Xx0rbzPxMec/view?)

I tried editing the binary code using hexeditor and inserted ad1 binary signature but it din't work

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will check the file for unwanted characters in the hex editor to solve this. remove them and open the file as a logical drive on the FTK manager. This will open and you will see it an an andriod backup drive